# Javascript for loop not iterating across array or values in an if statement not updating as planned

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Trying to return the highest 5 digit number out of any given number i.e 34858299999234
will return 99999

I think I have it narrowed down to the for loop not iterating the array properly OR the values for 'hold1' and 'hold2' are not updating.

---

```
function solution(digits){
  
  //Convert string to array to iterate through
  let arr = digits.split("");
  let final = 0;
  //iterate through the array in 5 sequence steps
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
      let hold1 = arr[i] + arr[i+1] +  arr[i+2]  + arr[i+3]  + arr[i+4];
      hold1 = parseInt(hold1,10); //converting string to int so if statement functions correctly
      let hold2 = arr[i+1] + arr[i+2]+ arr[i+3] +  arr[i+4]  + arr[i+5];
      hold2 = parseInt(hold2,10);
          if(hold1 >= hold2){        
             final = hold1;
          }else{
            final = hold2;
          }
    return final;
  }
  
}
```

---

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, **tell other readers what the expected behavior should be.** Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: What do you expect `arr[i+3]`, `arr[i+4]`, ... to be when `i === arr.length - 2` (the last value in the loop)?

Comment: You appear to `return final` inside you loop no matter what..  IOW: Your loop is totally pointless.

Comment: Keith is right...move that return statement out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

if you need a five digits result you need to change the for loop in something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 5; i++) {
```

Otherwise you will generate results shorter than 5 digits.

Also, I think you are missing the `Math.max` method that will compare two numbers to return the bigger one.

I rewrote your function this way:

```
function solution(digits) {
  let op = 0;
  let length = 5;
  let stringDigits = String(digits); /// <-- I use string instead of array
  if (stringDigits.length <= length) {
    return digits; /// <-- If input is shorter than 5 digits
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < stringDigits.length - length; i++) {
    const fiveDigitsValue = stringDigits.substr(i, length);
    op = Math.max(op, Number(fiveDigitsValue));
  }
  return op;
}
```